# Can someone help me understand Curry's paradox?

Tags: lo.logic

I understand the general concept, that if you define a statement X such that X = X -> Y, you can prove that X is true regardless of Y so you can then prove any statement. What I don't quite understand is how one proves that X is true.

I have tried to prove it using the three main ways of proving an implication, contradiction, contrapositive, and direct, but the last two methods are unsatisfactory.

Contradiction:
Suppose X is true and Y is false.
Then X -> Y is false.
But X = X -> Y
X cannot be both true and false.
So X cannot be true when Y is false.
So X -> Y is true, so X is true.
QED

This way I understand and seems fine, what trips me up is direct and contrapositive, with direct assuming what you are trying to show and contrapositive showing that X is both true and false.

Direct:
Suppose X is true.
Then since X = X -> Y is true and X is true, Y is true.
So X -> Y is true, and X is true.
QED

This seems to assume what we are trying to prove.

Contrapositive:
Suppose Y is false.
If X is true, then X -> Y is false, but X = X -> Y so X is false.
X cannot be both true and false, so X is false.
Therefore X -> Y is true, so X is true
QED

This is troubling because X has been shown to be both true and false.

I guess what I am asking is what is the accepted way to prove that a statement X = X -> Y is true to construct Curry's paradox, and why do some proof methods seem incorrect or contradictory?

Comment: This question would be more appropriate at math.stackexchange; this site is for research mathematics.

Answer (score 4):

A false statement implies all statements. So if $X$ were false, then $X\implies Y$ would be true. But you've assumed that $X\implies Y$ is the same as $X$ (or at least equivalent to $X$), so then $X$ would be true.

So, by assuming that $X$ is false, I've arrived at the contradiction that $X$ would also be true. That contradiction shows that $X$ can't be false.

So $X$ is true. According to your assumption, $X\implies Y$ is also true. Put those two truths together, and you infer that $Y$ is true.

EDIT: The preceding argument assumed that $X$ is true or false. It's probably sufficient for the present purpose, but if anyone wants a constructive proof, here goes: We're given both 
$$
(1)\ X\implies(X\implies Y)\quad\text{and}\quad
(2)\ (X\implies Y)\implies X.
$$
From (1), we get by (constructively valid) propositional logic $$\ (3)\ X\implies Y.$$ From this and (2), we get by Modus Ponens that $X$, and then by (3) and Modus Ponens $Y$.

Comment: While this is a very clear answer, and while your long history here indicates that you are more experienced with the culture than I am, I wonder if it might not be better to direct this (seemingly non-research-level) question to MSE before answering it.

Comment: @LSpice You're probably right; I wasn't paying attention to which site I was on.